# How to pass the id of dropdown on its onchange fn in razor html or mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am calling a function called `ChangeCurrency(ID)` on dropdown change.I need the id of the dropdown in the function `ChangeCurrency(ID)`.but unfortunately in razor html it shows this error:

```
PjtCostCurrencyID is undefined.
```

so how can I pass the id of the dropdown to the function.Pls help.

following is the code

```
 @Html.DropDownList("PjtCostCurrencyID", null, new { @onchange = "ChangeCurrency($PjtCostCurrencyID)" })
```

Comment: whats PjtCostCurrencyID? is that the id of dropdownlist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
  @Html.DropDownList("PjtCostCurrencyID", null, new { @onchange = "ChangeCurrency(this)" })

and in function

function ChangeCurrency(_this)
{
  var PjtCostCurrencyID =_this.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should return you the ID of the select element.

```
    var select_id = $(this).attr('id');
```